# Bing Map Drawing Tool Module - Initialization

Tags: bing-maps

i have a Geolocalisation Web Application and i Use Bing Maps as a Front End Map Tool, for the back end, i would be able to edit points and polygons, for this, i am using Bing Map Drawing Tools Module.

My Goal is to use the same map to add / or edit a shape depending on what is the content of certain textbox.

So, there is any way to init the map by a default drawn shape and pushpin?